# Joomla 3 Global Configuration missing css

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0, configuration-files, administrator

This is not really question, more an answer...

I recently updated Joomla to version: 3.4.8 and after that the Global configuration page was missing the CSS-styling.

I quickly tried solving it and came across alot of similar cases from searching Google... Some had "answers", but not and easy fix..So if anyone else is stuck with this problem, here is the solution :)

1. Run your FTP and locate the folder name "libraries" in your Joomla install on your server.
2. Then take a backup of this "Just in case".
3. Delete this folder and replace it width the same folder from a fresh Joomla install.

Some of the files in that folder was causing the issue, and if don't bother finder the specific file, then just do the above and the problem is solve.

Hope this helps someone :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Run your FTP and locate the folder name "libraries" in your Joomla install on your server.
2. Then take a backup of this "Just in case".
3. Delete this folder and replace it width the same folder from a fresh Joomla install.

Some of the files in that folder was causing the issue, and if don't bother finder the specific file, then just do the above and the problem is solve.

Hope this helps someone :D

Answer (score 1):

So basically you were hacked. Simply replacing the libraries and includes folder is enough to get your site online again, however it is not the solution. You need a complete security audit and review conducted.

Many hacks for Joomla install dodgy session or cache handlers - as a hook for them - and this can and will create an issue when loading the Configuration page.

Also if you are on a mac and you upload dot underscore ._ files to some parts of the libraries folder you can again kill the configuration page as Joomla is stupid and includes all the files in the folder irrespective of filename (actually a security issue in itself, but been that way for ages)